# How to create an index based on a time-based function in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, functions, timestamp

I have a function called `hot_rank` to rank posts, based on their score, and their newest_comment_time (basically a decaying power function):

```sql
create or replace function hot_rank(
  score numeric,
  published timestamp without time zone)
returns integer as $$
begin
  -- hours_diff:=EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timezone('utc',now()) - published))/3600
  return floor(10000*log(greatest(1,score+3)) / power(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() - published)/3600) + 2), 1.8))::integer;
end; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;
```

I then create an index on this table, using that function:

`create index idx_post_aggregates_active on post_aggregates (hot_rank(score, newest_comment_time) desc, newest_comment_time desc);`

Over time, I began to notice strange results, so I looked at the table, and when I ordered by the `hot_rank(...`, the numeric values seemed good, but the order was wrong.

I then ran `reindex` on that index, and everything sorted correctly again.

What would cause this index to "go bad" after a while? What's causing the index to sort wrongly? Am I incorrectly defining an actually mutable function as immutable?

What am I doing wrong here, and what's a way to fix this?

edit: here's the index:

`create index idx_post_aggregates_active on post_aggregates (hot_rank(score, newest_comment_time) desc, newest_comment_time desc);`

And the query:

```
select 
p.id,
p.name,
pa.newest_comment_time,
pa.score,
hot_rank(pa.score, pa.newest_comment_time)
from post p
inner join post_aggregates pa
on pa.post_id = p.id
order by hot_rank(pa.score, pa.newest_comment_time) desc, pa.newest_comment_time desc
limit 50;
```

Comment: "Am I incorrectly defining an actually mutable function as immutable?" -- obviously, because `now()` is not deterministic.

Comment: Is there any way around this problem? The indexed query is < 10 ms, and the regular query is > 2s.

Comment: What is the query?

Comment: select 
p.id,
p.name,
pa.newest_comment_time,
pa.score,
hot_rank(pa.score, pa.newest_comment_time)
from post p
inner join post_aggregates pa
on pa.post_id = p.id
order by hot_rank(pa.score, pa.newest_comment_time) desc, pa.newest_comment_time desc
limit 50;

Comment: And the index:

create index idx_post_aggregates_active on post_aggregates (hot_rank(score, newest_comment_time) desc, newest_comment_time desc);

Comment: I've edited the post to add the index and the query.

Comment: @mustaccio Is the answer to "how do I create an index based on a time-based function" ... you can't?

Comment: Obviously you can, because you did create one. However, it clearly doesn't work as you expect, so you _shouldn't_ create one.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Is it possible for postgres to have fast queries based on comparing rows based on a time function?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be an X-Y problem without proper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not immutable, yet it is declared to be immutable.  This deception will lead to corrupted to indexes, as you have discovered.  Each entry will be in the index with the score it had at the time it was inserted/updated.

The way to fix this is to take a step back and look at what you are trying to do.  What is the point of the power function at all?  <s>It won't change the ordering of the points</s> (well it will of course if they are not tied in greatest(1,score+3)), so what does it accomplish in your usage?  What is the point of converting to integer?  How long is data retained in the table?

Comment: Is there any way around this? The regular query is over 2 seconds, the indexed query is < 10 ms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ordering of the table that changes over time, you cannot persist it with an index. Rather, you have to calculate the order whenever you query the table.

Comment: Is there any way to speed this up? The regular query is over 2 seconds, the indexed query is < 10 ms.

Comment: You could write an SQL function that can be inlined rather than a PL/pgSQL function that cannot. But with a complicated expression like that, it will always be slow. Perhaps you could use a different, simpler function.